# Extending the Dirac operator on an open subset of a manifold and preserving positivity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry, index-theory

Let $M$ be a spin manifold and $U\subseteq M$ an open ball. Let $D$ be the Dirac operator on $M$ with respect to some Riemannian metric $g$, acting on sections of the spinor bundle $S\to M$. Suppose that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all compactly supported smooth sections $s\in C_c^\infty(S)$, we have $\|Ds\|\geq C\|s\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L^2$-norm.

Let $U_2$ be the double of the closure $\overline{U}\subseteq M$. Deform the metric $g$ on a small neighborhood $N\subseteq\overline{U}$ of the boundary $\partial\overline{U}$ so that it is product-type on $N$. This deformed metric extends smoothly to $U_2$ in the obvious way. Let $S_2$ denote the new spinor bundle over $U_2$ and $D_2$ the associated Dirac operator.

I'm wondering if it's possible for this procedure to preserve (even approximately) the lower bound for $D$. More precisely:

**Question 1:** Is it possible to do the deformation so that $\|D_2s\|\geq C\|s\|$ for all $s\in C_c^\infty(S_2)$?

**Question 2:** If not, then for any $\varepsilon>0$, is it possible to do the deformation so that $\|D_2s\|\geq (C-\varepsilon)\|s\|$ for all $s\in C_c^\infty(S_2)$?